# Replace values in column using logical vector

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

I have a dataframe in long form. The OTU column has ~428 unique ids with repeated measures resulting in 26,536 rows.

```
'data.frame':   26536 obs. of  18 variables:
 $ OTU        : chr  "109431" "109431" "109431" "109431" ...
 $ Sample     : chr  "m.ch.45" "m.ch.59" "m.ch.85" "m.ch.51" ...
 $ Abundance  : num  0.994 0.983 0.981 0.975 0.975 ...
 $ X.SampleID : Factor w/ 62 levels "m.ch.1","m.ch.101",..: 28 37 52 33 
                                                8 15 13 7 58 14 ...
 $ Family     : Factor w/ 89 levels 
    "f__","f__[Acidaminobacteraceae]",..: 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 
                                              ...
```

Of the unique ids in column OTU, I want to focus on 9 of them (top9names).
I made a logical vector with all OTUs in the top 9 as TRUE and all those that are not as FALSE

```
matches <- qd_melted$OTU %in% top9names
```

For these 9 OTU names I want to preserve the corresponding Family name (column5). For the other OTU names (~419), I want to replace the value in the Family column with "Other taxa".
Any tips on how to code this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When adding a new value to factors you need to update the levels first. Here's one way -

```
levels(qd_melted$Family) <- c(levels(qd_melted$Family), "Other taxa")

qd_melted$Family[!matches] <- "Other taxa"
```